# Google API access token meaning

Tags: google-api

Somebody has created a system which use Google API. It happens that I have been using this system for several months to upload files to G Drive and it worked very well.
However today I realized in the following string that there was an expiry date (not updated until today) which prevent from uploading files. My understanding is that a token is generated every time my code is requesting API access, but this shows the same access_token and refresh token with expiry date. I tried to read official doc without clear understanding. Can you explain simply what I should think about it and hint at how I should re generate the needed token please.

```
{"access_token": "xxx", "client_id": "yyy", "client_secret": "nnn", "refresh_token": "bbb", "token_expiry": "2021-02-24T05:33:24Z", "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", "user_agent": null, "revoke_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke", "id_token": null, "id_token_jwt": null, "token_response": {"access_token": "xxx", "expires_in": 3599, "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "token_type": "Bearer"}, "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"], "token_info_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo", "invalid": true, "_class": "OAuth2Credentials", "_module": "oauth2client.client"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How much i understood it is that as we need multiple parameters to access a Google API which include authentication etc. As there are multiple steps to validate an API call, if they succeed, we are provided with an `access_token` which now represents that all the processes (or authentication etc) was successfull and now the `access_token` is a proof for that. So after that, only the token will be checked (until its expiry date) and the process will repeat after the expiration.

> The authorization sequence begins when your application redirects a browser to a Google URL; the URL includes query parameters that indicate the type of access being requested. Google handles the user authentication, session selection, and user consent. The result is an authorization code, which the application can exchange for an access token and a refresh token.

> The application should store the refresh token for future use and use the access token to access a Google API. Once the access token expires, the application uses the refresh token to obtain a new one.

More details [Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#installed)